# write dataset to sql table using asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, dataset

I've successfully imported a tab-delimited file into a dataset in asp.net (C#). I can bind the dataset to a gridview, and see my data (that part works fine).

Now I want to insert that dataset table (the only table in the dataset) into a sql table using an INSERT command - I don't know enough about datasets to figure it out.

Comment: Google it, it's pretty easy to find examples

Comment: Make an attempt at the issue! Start by reading the [DataSet documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you won't use the INSERT command, to insert a new table you're going to need this query:

```
string query = "CREATE TABLE myTable (column1 INT, column2 NVARCHAR(10))";
```

Source: [Creating Databases and tables using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701574/creating-databases-and-tables-using-c-sharp)

Where 'column1' is your column's name and INT the type. You can see more about the types here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp
and you can also see more SQL commands here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_syntax.asp